# LaTeX Error: File `mstyle.sty' not found. [\selectlanguage]

Tags: packages, languages

I am trying to compile a template that I have received but I am having problems :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mstyle}
\selectlanguage{english}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\onehalfspace

\input{tex/introduction_chapter}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this gives me

```
Errors:

./x.tex:3: LaTeX Error: File `mstyle.sty' not found. [\selectlanguage]
```

I am using `texlive` (2013.20140215-1) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Mstyle is not a known package (at least returns nothing on ctan) didn't you get it along with the template

Comment: The package needs to be at a location where TeX is looking for it, for example in the current working directory.